# Does increasing the length of wire increase the work (energy) needed to move electrons from the negative terminal to the positive one?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, potential-energy

Imagine a circuit which consists of a battery and a resistor with a certain wire length. Suppose that the battery supplies 9 Volts. I know that it is the electromotive force which pushes the electrons from the negative terminal to the positive terminal. Does 9 Volts mean that the energy needed to move one coulomb from the negative terminal to the positive terminal is 9 Joules? If so, then what happens if we have a longer wire? It seems that that more work is done to move the electron but the battery is still supplying 9 Volts so the work to move 1 coulomb is still 9 Joules. Shouldn't the work depend on distance?!

Comment: Well, the resistance of a wire will increase with its length. If you compare two circuits with that only differ in the length of their wires, you may find that the one with longer wires will have slightly more resistance, thus lowering the current for the same voltage level.

Comment: @corcholatacolormarengo That's an answer!

Comment: How does lowering the current answer his question? doesn't matter even if 1 C of charge flows,every coulomb will have 9 joules of energy only, right?so how will that 1 c will reach to the other end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how long the wire is if the voltage across the wire is 9 volts it means 9 Joules of work is done in moving 1 Coulomb of charge from one end of the wire to the other. But increasing the length of the wire increases its resistance and reduces the current for the same potential difference (voltage),  per Ohms law $V=IR$.  The work per unit charge in moving the charge along the length of wire does not change unless there is a change in potential difference between the ends of the wire.

However, a reduction in current means less Coulombs per second going from one end of the wire to the other. That results in a reduction in the power delivered by the battery. The rate at which work is done (power, $P$) is $P=VI$, = Joules/Coulomb x Coulombs/s= Joules/s= watts.

> but why the length doesn't matter, the resistance of the wire is very
>   tiny so we can consider the wire has no resistance.now, doesn't moving
>   the electron a longer distance mean doing more work on it? .I want to
>   know why the length of the wire doesn't matter?

If the wire has zero resistance, then from Ohms law, $V=IR$, the voltage (potential difference) between the ends of the wire must also be zero. Since voltage is defined as the work per Coulomb of charge to move the charge between the two points, if the voltage between the two points is zero, no work would be done to move the charge between the two points of a zero resistance wire, regardless of how long it is.

So you might ask, what happens to the 9 volts the battery produces if it is connected to a zero resistance wire?

A real battery always has internal resistance.  Otherwise it could deliver an infinite amount of current to a wire of zero resistance, since $I=\frac{V}{0}=∞$.

The circuits below shows a real battery with an emf of 9 volts and internal battery resistance of $R_b$ in series with the wire. The top circuit shows the wire having resistance R. The bottom shows the wire having zero resistance, as you asked about.

The current in the bottom circuit is

$$I=\frac{9v}{R_b}$$

All of the batteries 9 volt emf is across its internal resistance $R_b$.  There is no voltage across the wire. Therefore no work is done moving charge in the wire connected between the positive and negative terminals of the battery regardless of the length of the wire. All the work the battery does is in moving the charge through its internal resistance $R_b$..

**Bottom Line:** Changing the length of the wire only matters if it changes the potential difference (voltage) between the ends of the wire.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but why the length doesn't matter, the resistance of the wire is very tiny so we can consider the wire has no resistance.now, doesn't moving the electron a longer distance mean doing more work on it? .I want to know why the length of the wire doesn't matter?

Comment: @MahmoudAmin I have revised my answer to better explain the significance of the length of the wire and the work required to move charge in the wire. I have also included a response to your follow up question. Hope this better clarifies things for you. Bob

Comment: Thank you a lot for this simple answer .

Comment: I didn't understand the answer,can u please explain it here in a more simple language

Comment: @AakashGarain You'll have to be more specific. What part don't you understand?

Comment: In short,nothing, current is decreased,then how does current being decreased helps 1c of charge to move across a longer wire,after all,the voltage source is providing it a fixed energy

Comment: @AakashGarain "nothing"?. I think you meant "everything". In any event, I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying. Sorry.

Comment: I mean to say I understood nothing

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if I have understood you correctly, your doubt is not whether the length of the wire affects the circuit, but if the work done is the same from one end to another, right?

Because you already know that ideal wires have zero resistance. That means that it is not relevant to have $1 \; \text{m}$ or $10 \; \text{m}$; if it is an ideal wire, the current is not affected by it, so the length doesn't matter. [unless yo care about wavelengths]

However, real wires have a tiny but non-zero resistance, so the longer they are, the more resistance you add to the circuit, so the current decreases (slightly)

This has already been addressed here, I think there's no doubt here. If so, add a comment.

---

### Work done

So, if I understood you correctly, your question is something like: "why doesn't the length matter, if $W= \text{Force} \times \text{distance}$ and the battery applies a constant energy?" Am I right that it was your question?

Well, if so, the answer is an important conceptual idea: the electric field inside the battery is different than that of the rest of the circuit.

You know that the electrostatic force is conservative. That means that the work done by the electrostatic force does not depend on the path followed, the work done depends only on the initial and final positions.

When this happens, you can define an electrostatic potential (voltage).

Okay, but, with moving charges, we're not in electrostatics anymore. We talk about "electric" field, rather than electrostatic. This one is more general.

Can we still apply our knowledge of electrostatics? Yes, but only in points where $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=\vec{0}$

This happens in the rest of the circuit. That's why we can still use a electric potential, although the charges are moving.

But there is a region where $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E} \neq \vec{0}$. Otherwise there wouldn't be energy for the charges to move. That region is the battery.

Inside the battery, there is a different electric field, which is a **non-conservative** electric field, and that means that the work done by it does depend on the path.

Inside the battery, the work done rises the charges from $0\; \text{V}$ to $9\; \text{V}$, but following that specific path.

In sum, the conclusions are:

> A battery is "something that takes one end at $0V$ and injects $9\; \text{V}$ at the other end". It's like a pump that takes $0 \;\text{V}$ and raises it to $9V$.
>
> Inside the battery, the electric field behaves differently.
>
> However, in the rest of the circuit, the electric field keeps being conservative, so that the voltage exists. And, what's more, the work done does not depend on the path.

In a less-technical way, a classical (non-rigorous) and easier analogy would be something like this:

The battery accelerates charges. There is force inside the battery.
After being released from the battery, the electrons do not suffer a force anymore. They are only slowed down in resistances and other elements of the circuit, but they are not accelerated forth.

If they are not accelerated, there is no force, there is no work, regardless of the path.

Comment: "After being released from the battery, the electrons do not suffer a force anymore." You should clarify that the electrons will not experience a force is true only if a wire of zero resistance is connected to the battery, because then there would be no voltage across the wire and all the battery emf will appear across its internal resistance. When a wire of finite resistance is connected across the battery terminals there will be a voltage, call it V,  across the wire. The battery then does work equal to $VQ$ moving charge $Q$ through the resistor. Work requires force.

Comment: That's true. Of course I was supposing ideal wires all the time. But, as you say, if there is a voltage gradient, there is a force because there is an electric field from the biggest to the lowest potential.